# Postgresql 9.3 replication: Preventing wal-files from building up, if receiver goes offline

Tags: postgresql

I have a streaming replication running between two servers.

I just upgraded to postgresql 9.3 from 9.2. Earlier on in my 9.2 setup, I have tried that my slave server went offline due to a network outage. This resulted in unshipped wal-log files building up and taking up space VERY fast on my master server.

Can I prevent this in an easy way in 9.3?

I have seen the new [wal_sender_timeout](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-replication.html) config, but I am unsure what exactly it does?

What's the best way of preventing wal-files from building up on sender if receiver goes offline in 9.3?

Comment: What's your `archive_command` doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `wal_keep_segments` to a low enough value that WAL will be discarded before `pg_xlog` fills up.

If you're also using WAL archiving with an `archive_command`, Pg will keep on trying until it successfully sends the WAL or runs out of space. Don't have your master copy the WAL directly to the replica; instead put it on some reliable high availability storage that the replica also has access to.